# Is it possible to replace Twilio's default ringing sound with some melody?

Tags: twilio

So the idea is pretty simple: to make caller to listen some nice melody instead of default ring beeps.
I have already looked at Twilio tutorials, but the only thing i found is that it is possible with queued calls. 
Does such feature available with  verb and not using queues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you dropped your caller into a conference you could set the wait music while you dialled another party into the call. That's not much different to using a queue though. There's no way to just set the dialling tone while the phone is ringing, so I would recommend one of these options.

Also note, the phone may ring before Twilio is able to deal with it. That is out of our control, so you may not get your music for the entire ringing period.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!